# Bash script arguments, require or fill in specific character

Tags: string, bash

I am writing a bash script that will output a .tgz file to a specific directory, /tmp/ by default
I would like to provide an option to override this directory and I have chosen to do so using arguments provided at the command line

```
    while getopts d: option
    do
    case "${option}" in
    d) dir=${OPTARG};;
    esac
    done
```

As written, this works but I've run into a snag depending on user input
The name of my .tgz file is also a variable and my code that brings this all together is

```
    output="$dir""$name"
```

The problem that I run into is if the user runs

```
    ./script -d /home/user
```

My resulting path and filename end up as

```
    /home/userfilename.tgz
```

I need to either enforce a requirement for a trailing / or insert one if the user did not.
While it works, if I change my output variable to

```
    output="$dir"/"$name"
```

If the user does provide a trailing / I end up with something like this and I am trying to keep my output aesthetic.

```
    /home/user//filename.tgz
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line

```
output="${output//\/\///}"
```

after joining `dir` and `name`.

It looks complicated, but what it does is it replaces two slashes with one.

You may find more info in [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22587).

Comment: Provided your file name does not begin with multiple slashes, POSIX  treat multiple slashes as single slashes, so no real problem here to enforce a trailing slash at end of `$dir`